# Apache ssl proxy unwanted redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, proxy, virtualhost

I'm running ubuntu server 12.04. I want to secure access to a python app via apache ssl proxy. I have

```
sudo a2ensite erp.mydomain.com
```

And I have in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com erp.mydomain.com
```

- -http://erp.mydomain.com redirects to -https://erp.mydomain.com **OK**
- -https://erp.mydomain.com proxy to -https://erp.mydomain.com/web/webclient/home **OK**
- -http://mydomain.com goes to my regular website in /var/www/ **OK**
- https://mydomain.com redirects to http://mydomain.com/web/webclient/home leading to error: "The requested URL /web/webclient/home was not found on this server." **Not OK**

I don't understand this redirection, any pointers would help. Here is my erp.mydomain.com file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName erp.mydomain.com
Redirect / https://erp.mydomain.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName erp.mydomain.com
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass        /   http://127.0.0.1:8069/
ProxyPassReverse /   http://127.0.0.1:8069/
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1  
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

block in your regular mydomain.com site file, then the problem is that Apache will serve the first virtualhost configured when there are no other matches.  Add a virtualhost for that servername and it should be solved.

If you do, then you may be having a problem with SNI not properly working, either on the client side (not supported in IE-on-XP) or on the server side (12.04 should have a proper version of OpenSSL though).  In this case, if `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck` is off, the client is served the default first vhost, rather than an error message.

Finally, make sure you have setup name-based vhosts on both *.80 and *.443:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more like your website is sending an HTTP redirect to the client.  As the server and the client both do not know about the proxy it just escapes.

Use a rewrite rule similar to this

```
    ReWriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/web/webclient/home/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/web/webclient/home
```

So when the redirect is sent, it is detected and re-written to point back to the https server before the client sees it.